# Would that sentence be clear and acceptable?

Tags: meaning

"Once lost, one tends to understand the value of one thing better, and when gaining it again, it will be all the more invaluable than ever before."

Comment: @Ivan J. F. What do you think? Do you think it is acceptable or unacceptable? Why?

Comment: What are your specific concerns in this sentence? The general grammar needs a few tweaks including a fix for the misplaced modifier "once lost". Who's lost? One? Something?  In general, new users of English should avoid wordy sentences - too error-prone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As a BrE speaker I would

- remove either "ever" or "before"
- change "one thing" to "something"
- rephrase "when gaining it again" as "when regaining it"
- change "all the more invaluable" to "more valuable" because, like "unique", "invaluable" is an absolute.

So I would rewrite the sentence as

> Once lost, one tends to understand the value of something better, and when regaining it, it will be more valuable than ever.

Comment: I find the sentence still a bit awkward. The "once lost" start seems to indicate that it is me who is getting lost. I have to stop and puzzle over that, and connect up the "something" to the "once." Maybe "Losing a thing makes you better understand its value..." or some such change.

Comment: @puppetsock I agree, the entire sequence needs revising. I was focussing on individual parts. Perhaps "Once something is lost..."

Comment: That's been very helpful. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Another thing: When I read the quote you provided, it took me a second to realise that the first "Once lost" was referring to "one thing". I mistakenly thought it was saying "once one is lost", but it was really saying "once one thing is lost". Perhaps that should be clarified, unless you feel context will make that immediately clear.

Also, the tone of the sentence seems very formal/lofty. If that's not something you intended, you may wish to edit that to a more familiar register. At the moment, the sentence reads like a quote from a novel or movie or famous person.

Comment: It helps a lot. Thank you.